# How do screen readers read <p> tags if they aren't focusable by default?

Tags: html, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I'm currently learning about accessiblity and trying to implement some features like a "skip to content" button. Which skips navigation elements and goes directly to content in my case `<h1>` with some paragraphs below `<p>`.

But when using the screen reader it doesn't focus at all on the `<p>`s and therefore doesn't read them.

Comment: this [article](https://accessibility.oit.ncsu.edu/it-accessibility-at-nc-state/developers/accessibility-handbook/mouse-and-keyboard-events/skip-to-main-content/) could be helpful